# Add trailing slash to string variable

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

[[ "$#" -gt 0 ]] && last_argument="${@:$#}" || last_argument=""
[[ -d $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}/" || \
    [[ -f $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}" || loc=""

list="ls -dlth $loc*/"

echo -e "$list"
eval "$list"
```

What I want it to do, is to check if the last argument is

- a directory, execute `ls -dlth $loc/*/`, (but it doesn't)
- a file, produce an error (which it does),
- empty, execute `ls -dlth */` (which it does)

Now the problem is that in the line where I say `loc="${last_argument}/"`, no `/` is being added to the string variable, and the command being executed is `ls -dlth $loc*/` which produces a different result. How can I fix this?

I tried escaping `/` with a `\`, but it didn't work:

```sh
loc="${last_argument}\/"
```

Running it with `set -xv` prints this:

```sh
[[ "$#" -gt 0 ]] && last_argument="${@:$#}" || last_argument=""
+ [[ 2 -gt 0 ]]
+ last_argument=/home/amir/Pictures
[[ -d $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}/" || \
    [[ -f $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}" || loc=""
+ [[ -d /home/amir/Pictures ]]
+ loc=/home/amir/Pictures/
+ loc=/home/amir/Pictures
```

Comment: Try running the script under `set -xv` to see what the variables really contain.

Comment: have you tried   https://shellcheck.net

Comment: So you have it - don't create if-else expressions with `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
[[ -d $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}/" ||
[[ -f $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}" || loc=""
```

is parsed as:

```
(
   (
       ( 
          [[ -d $last_argument ]] &&
          loc="${last_argument}/" 
       ) ||
       [[ -f $last_argument ]] 
    ) && 
    loc="${last_argument}"
) ||
loc=""
```

In your sample execution the `[[ -d $last_argument ]]` exits with a zero exit status (success), so `loc="${last_argument}/"` is executed. Then `[[ -d $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}/"` returns with a zero exit status (success), so the `[[ -f $last_argument ]]` is **not** executed, but the whole `[[ -d $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}/" || [[ -f $last_argument ]]` also exits with a zero exit status (success) (because the left side of `||` exited with zero exit status (success)). That means that `loc="${last_argument}"` is executed, so you finally see `+ loc=/home/amir/Pictures` in your script execution.

Note that `\` after `||` before a newline is not needed (you can even add a comment there).

I think you could group your statements:

```
{ [[ -d $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}/" ;} ||
{ [[ -f $last_argument ]] && loc="${last_argument}" ;} ||
loc=""
```

Or just use `if-elif-else-fi` to have control over what happens.